# Почему дочерний блок сдвигает родителя?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый день!

Собственно, не совсем понимаю, почему при изменении margin у блока #task, изменяется положение блока #field.

```js
onload = function(){
 O("begin").onclick = function(){
  S("first").display="none";
  S("field").display="block";
 }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond');

body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
 background-color: lightyellow;

}
.container{
 width: 700px;
 height: 500px;
 margin:50px auto;
 background-color: #D9F1E4;
}
header{
 width: 100%;
 height:50px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid red;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
#first{
 width: 500px;
 margin:50px auto;
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 1em;
}
h1{
 color: black;
 font-size: 2em;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-left: 30px;

}
h2{
 padding: 50px 5px;
}
#first > button{
 width: 250px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 30px;
 font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
 font-size: 1.0em;
 background-color: #D9F1E4;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 
}
.field{
 widtH: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display:none;
}
#task{
 width: 70%;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 50px auto;
 border-radius: 5px;
 overflow:hidden;

}
#word{
 width: 80%;
 height : 100%;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
}
#score{
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color:red;
 float:left;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vchubar.ru/service_files/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/scramble.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vchubar/mylib.js/21eaa6c8/mylib.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/scramble/scramble.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header><h1>Scrambled!</h1></header>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="first" id="first">
   <h2>
    You have three chances to unscramble the word.<br>
    If you succeed, you get a point.<br>
    If you fail, you lose a point.
   </h2>
   <button id="begin">Let`s go!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="field" id="field">
   <div id="task">
    <div id="word">
    </div>
    <div id="score">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="result">
    <div id="enter">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  
</body>
</html>
```

Прошу вас помочь мне в решении данной проблемы.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложно сказать в чем причина такого поведения, кроме того, что "так и задумано", причина что-то в духе "потому что дочерний элемент не видит явно границы родителя", ну или это просто "фича". В любом случае знаю только 3 варианта решения:

```
.field { padding: .1px; } // Или другой положительный
```

или

```
.field { border: .1px solid transparent; } // Или другой положительный
```

или

```
.field { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Схлопываются поля, потому что S("field").display="*block*" генерирует блок.

Подробней можешь здесь почитать: http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy

Comment: Спасибо, но тогда в таком случае, почему  например .field { overflow: hidden; }, расхлопывает обратно?

Comment: @vladimirch, также схлопывание не срабатывает при соблюдении некоторых условий:
    - для элементов, у которых значение overflow задано как auto, hidden или scroll схлопывание не действует для их дочерних элементов;
    - у элементов, к которым применяется свойство clear, не схлопывается верхний отступ с нижним отступом родительского элемента.